# How I explain New France not having their Middle East?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, history

In an alternate history I am designing, France wins the Seven Years War and does not lose their land claims in America. A problem I have reached though is explaining why land east of the Mississippi winds up in American control.

How can I explain why the land east of the Mississippi (represented by the red line) would come into American control?

[image]

Comment: As an aside, you're going to change _a lot_ of social stuff. In particular, Quebec's history is fundamentally rooted in having lost that war.

Comment: You might want to change "Middle East" in the title.  Means an entirely different area to most people :-)

Comment: I concur. That's not the [Middle East as world knows the name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_East).

Comment: @isanae I know, and I am

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The American Revolution Happened Earlier

The reason that the French won the 7 Years War is that the America Revolution happened in the midst of it, and France recognized the territory of the newly independent USA in exchange for a cessation of hostilities on that front.

Comment: Seems like a plausible alternative, but I'd love to see it expanded more

Comment: This would also give a reason that the British lost the Revolution, since French aid to the Americans might be unlikely in the situation, at least unlikely if the French actually give the Americans more land. But with the British distracted, American settlers might have a chance to win.

Comment: @DonyorM I'm not sure if this is news to you, but the American settlers did with the revolution...

Comment: @kingledion I know, but French aid had a large part in their victory. If the French were at war, they would be unlikely to give aid and land to the colonies, simply so they wouldn't fight them. If the French aided the colonies in the revolution, part of the treaty would likely include a cessation of hostilities.

Answer (score 9):

## No explanation needed

These were claims, not territory. There were no permanent French inhabitants, just a few soldiers, traders, and trappers. There were no settlers and families like there was in English North America.

If American settlers just moved in an occupied the land, the ownership would resolve itself quickly. Even if the French won the 7 Years war, there was not a mass emigration from France to settle new lands as there was Irish and Scottish settlement in the 13 colonies. The US would have quickly outnumbered the French, with the only remaining dense French settlements around Montreal and New Orleans.

It seems almost pre-ordained that American settlement would overtake most of the Ohio Valley, and probably the rest of the Great Plains as well.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, the Americans have advanced west across the Appalachians and are now firmly in control of the east bank of the Mississippi River. This would also suggest they are in control of the southern shores of the Great lakes as well, and have an outlet on the Gulf of Mexico, sandwiched between the remainder of New France and Spanish Florida.

How the Americans come into control of this is relatively straightforward, the population of the American colonies was vastly greater than New France, and they were also concentrated along the coastal region rather than spread over a vast swath of North America. Sheer weight of numbers would overwhelm the peoples of New France, and the thinly settled wilderness would be filled with small freeholds, villages and eventually towns as American colonists struck west seeking land and opportunities. These settlers would probably be led by current and former "Rangers", skilled in scouting and wilderness warfare, and capable of protecting the settlers against French, Quebecois and Indian forces.

Indeed what you seem to be describing isn't a clear cut victory by the French at all, but rather a stalemate, where the French may be rapidly fortifying the west bank of the Mississippi and the northern shores of the Great Lakes in anticipation of another push by the Americans into the rich lands of the Great Plains.

The French are also at a great disadvantage in that their social and political structure is actually more Feudal in nature than the structures erected by the colonies. Much of the French nobility, and presumably much of the regular French Regiments and [Troupes de la marine](http://infogalactic.com/info/Troupes_de_la_marine) would be in the core of New France itself, along the St Lawrence river. Their agriculture and economy in general is far less productive than their American rivals, and Metropolitan France most likely considers New France to be "*quelques arpents de neige*", and not worth expending extra resources on (especially compared to money making ventures like the Caribbean sugar trade, African slaves or their possessions in India, assuming the British haven't prevailed in these areas either).

The ultimate question will be settled by a combination of population, logistics and social dynamics. The Americans have the advantages in all three areas, and the New French simply do not have the population or resources to hold the Mississippi river line against the Americans flooding across looking for new lands and opportunities.